# ESXi 6.5 - Can't expand capacity of a VMFS5 volume

Tags: vmware-esxi

Esxi Version 6.5.0 (Build 4887370)

I have a volume that has completely filled up (4.11Gb free out of 7.26Tb). When I select the volume in the web admin interface there is the option to "Increase Capacity" When I click on "Increase Capacity" the dialog hangs:

[image]

I have tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge in hopes that it was a browser issue. It behaves the same in all three. I have looked in the log files and the only thing I see is in the syslog:

```
2020-01-09T15:05:27Z sfcb-CIMXML-Processor[86704]: [root] SendCmd on root/dcim/sysman:DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule.InstanceID="DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule1"
```

2020-01-09T15:05:27Z sfcb-CIMXML-Processor[86706]: [root] SendCmd on root/dcim/sysman:DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule.InstanceID="DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule1"
2020-01-09T15:05:58Z sfcb-CIMXML-Processor[86711]: [root] SendCmd on root/dcim/sysman:DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule.InstanceID="DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule1"
2020-01-09T15:05:58Z sfcb-CIMXML-Processor[86713]: [root] SendCmd on root/dcim/sysman:DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule.InstanceID="DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule1"
2020-01-09T15:06:28Z sfcb-CIMXML-Processor[86715]: [root] SendCmd on root/dcim/sysman:DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule.InstanceID="DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule1"
2020-01-09T15:06:29Z sfcb-CIMXML-Processor[86717]: [root] SendCmd on root/dcim/sysman:DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule.InstanceID="DCIM_OEM_DataAccessModule1"

I do have another volume that I **CAN** get to the next step on in the "Increase Capacity" process so I know that generally the Increase capacity works. The problem seems to be volume specific.

If I launch the VM it very quickly locks up so I really can't use the web interface to pare down the backups to free some space. I have been able to SSH to the VM but I have the same result - it locks up very quickly.

I am assuming that I cannot Increase Capacity on that volume for some reason because it is too full.

Does anybody have any ideas or help on this issue?

Comment: What version of 6.5 is this? There used to be a bug like that for non-patched vanilla versions where the web client would get stuck - you could get around it by either resizing it via the command line or using the 6.0 Windows client (or by upgrading to 6.5U1 or newer)

Comment: @Miuku 6.5.0 (Build 4887370). Good to know. I have a raid array rebuilding at the moment (adding more disks) so I will wait on that. I will look into expanding via command line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've hit the problem in question, here's the link to it; https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2150383